# zkClient can not be Serializabled , sparkstreaming write kafka offset to zookeeper

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

My project includes ZooKeeper, Kafka and Spark Streaming. Problem is `zkClient` cannot be serialized when I try using Spark Streaming to write Kafka offset to ZooKeeper. I have seen several GitHub projects such as: https://github.com/ippontech/spark-kafka-source

```
//save the offsets

kafkaStream.foreachRDD(rdd => offsetsStore.saveOffsets(topic, rdd))

def saveOffsets(topic: String, rdd: RDD[_]): Unit = {

    logger.info("Saving offsets to ZooKeeper")
    val stopwatch = new Stopwatch()

    val offsetsRanges = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges
    offsetsRanges.foreach(offsetRange => logger.debug(s"Using ${offsetRange}"))

    val offsetsRangesStr = offsetsRanges.map(offsetRange => s"${offsetRange.partition}:${offsetRange.fromOffset}").mkString(",")
    logger.debug(s"Writing offsets to ZooKeeper: ${offsetsRangesStr}")
    **ZkUtils.updatePersistentPath(zkClient, zkPath, offsetsRangesStr)**

    logger.info("Done updating offsets in ZooKeeper. Took " + stopwatch)

}
```

As the code: `kafkaStream.foreachRDD(rdd => offsetsStore.saveOffsets(rdd))` will execute in driver `private val zkClient = new ZkClient(zkHosts, 30000, 30000,ZKStringSerializer)` in object `offsetStore` but the `zkClient` cannot be serialized how does it work?

Comment: kafkaStream.foreachRDD(rdd => {
     rdd.foreachPartition(x=>offsetsStore.saveOffsets( rdd))
   })     this ll be ok but foreachpartition will be executed severl times as the partitions num

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define `zkClient` as `@transient lazy val`, which means it will not be serialized between driver and executors (this is the `@transient` part), but rather will be initialized anew, in each and every instance of the class which contains the above code (this is the `lazy` part).

You can read more about this pattern here:
http://fdahms.com/2015/10/14/scala-and-the-transient-lazy-val-pattern/

Comment: ty:)   I have tried this way before but failed ,and now it works ,so it means initialized zkClient just be executed in driver?

Comment: It definitely means that zkClient will not be serialized.
I'm not 100% sure where the code which iterates over `offsetsRanges` runs.
In any case, each place where this code will run, will initialize a separate instance of zkClient.
Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Only in the driver it can get the RDD not a RDD partition,so offsetsRanges can only be executed in driver and i think that is why zkClient   need not to be serialized.